# How to use line chart to graphically show the correlation between two variables ( two columns from a same DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, linechart

I am trying to graphically show if there is a correlation between two variables(two columns from a same DataFrame(df)) by using a **line chart**. I already checked that there is a  correlation between these two columns(using the `df.corr()` method ) and found a value (-0.986). However, i would like to know how to see it using a line chart .

```py
# Set variables for columns
x = df['mark'] #[92,92,32,95] #sampledata
y = df['time'] #[130,120,175,120](minutes) #sampledata

#display correlation between all columns in the dataFrame
print(df.corr())

#Select the correlation between the columns
df_corr = pd.DataFrame(df1[[x, y]].corr()).round(2)

plt.plot(df_corr,'--')
```

i obtain :
[image: line chart mark/time]
and i do not understand.

Comment: I don't understand how line chart can give you an information about the correlation between 2 variables. In your graph the correlation is 0.84 between the two variables. At each corner you have a value from the correlation matrix 1 = (var1, var1), 0.84 = (var1, var2) and reciprocally

Comment: If you want a line, then you should do a regression. For `.corr`, a heatmap is the correct option.

Comment: Okay thanks, maybe it's me who doesn't understand what I need to do. I'm working on a project as a beginner and there's a question where, after creating a dataframe, I have to << use a line graph to show if there is a correlation between higher grades (df['marks]) and more time spent on campus (df['time']) >>.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```
# Python env: pip install seaborn
# Anaconda env: conda install seaborn
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'mark': [92,92,32,95], 'time': [130,120,175,120]})
sns.heatmap(df.corr().round(2))
plt.show()
```

[image: Heatmap]